# Network Anlayst hierarchy evaluator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, network-analyst

Working with ArcGIS (v10.2.2) Network Analyst and reformating the road network with a hierarchy evaluator and receive the following error message:

> The field evaluator result statement has multiple lines. Use the
>   prelogic to specify multiple.

In the `Field Evaluators` dialog I have entered:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
Select Case [EVG_FC] 
     Case 1, 2: level = 1 
     Case 3, 4: level = 2
     Case 5, 6: level = 3 
     Case Else: level = 2
End Select 

Value =  level
```

Any idea why or what the error message is telling me?

Comment: What syntax are you using (VB/Python)? I'm assuming Value = level isn't in the pre-logic box, but in the lower expression box (and you haven't actually typed value= there. For these kinds of dialogs, with the pre-logic script, a screenshot is often helpful to eliminate confusion. I notice you're not dimming a variable up top first (ie, level).